# How do I get the decimal places of a floating point number which has only zeros in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

How the `getDecimals` function will be look like?

```
(12.0000).getDecimals() // 4
```

*P.S.
All `stackoverflow solutions` works without zeros, but if I have only zeros, it returns me just 0 decimals*

Comment: Not possible. `12.0000` gets simplified to `12` by the interpreter

Comment: take a string instead of a number.

Comment: how are you getting `12.0000` is it a user input - it'd be a string, `"12.0000"`, so therefore it would be possible

Comment: `"12.000".split(".")[1].length` will be `4`

Comment: @messerbill eeeeuh I guess it's a typo? `"12.000".split(".")[1].length` will be `3`. You probably meant `"12.0000".split(".")[1].length`

Comment: @briosheje yes i meant "12.0000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. 12.0000 will always be transformed to 12 in JavaScript compiler.